# How to get the value of the innerHTML of a viewChild in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-template, viewchild

I need the value of a viewChild in Angular in order to check if it is an empty string or not.

My ViewChild looks like this:

```
@ViewChild('myItem', { static: true }) myItem: ElementRef;
```

I get the value like this:

```
console.log('itemType', this.myItem.nativeElement.firstChild); // returns "TESTSTRING"
```

In the console the value looks like this: "TESTSTRING" which is a string, but if I check with typeof it says that it is an object:

```
console.log('itemType', typeof this.myItem.nativeElement.firstChild); // returns object
```

I'd like to check it like this:

```
this.myItemIsEmpty = this.myItem.nativeElement.firstChild === ''; // returns always false
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: First Child is a node. Try adding `.textContent` to that. But even wanting to read the nativ text of a node is an... interesting... Use case in angular

Comment: @pascalpuetz Ok, now it always returns true :D. Very confusing...

Comment: @pascalpuetz Ok, it works with textContent, but I have to use it in the ngAfterViewInit() lifecycle method. You can post your comment as an answer. I'll approve it :)

Comment: sure, I added my comment as an answer - with a bit more explanation for future readers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following part `this.myItem.nativeElement.firstChild` returns an element of type `ChildNode` - which represents a DOM element. To get the text of that, you need to use the `textContent` property.

```
@Component({/* ...*/})
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
   @ViewChild('myItem', { static: true }) myItem: ElementRef;

   // Only try to access @ViewChild/@ContentChild in/after AfterViewInit as DOM might not be rendered otherwise
   public ngAfterViewInit():void {
      this.myItemIsEmpty = this.myItem.nativeElement.firstChild.textContent === '';
   }
}
```